# How to declare a date with string in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can print the date today using the code `DateTime.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`

But what if I want to combine some of it with string such as `DateTime.now.last_month.strftime("25/%m/%Y 00:00")`

Is it possible to achieve this?

I want to select the 25th day of the last month and use it in a condition.

This condition `if DateTime.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") > DateTime.now.last_month.strftime("25/%m/%Y 00:00")` returns false (with string)

While this condition `if if DateTime.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") > DateTime.now.last_month.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")` returns true (without string)

Comment: You mean  to say you have this string only `25/%m/%Y 00:00` and you want to get the date in same format  ?

Comment: I want the day and time to be fixed while keeping the month and the year dynamic and auto adjusting.

Comment: You should compare _dates_ not _strings_ in the first place.

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I'm asking on how to convert that string into a date.

Comment: @DavidAngulo do you know what are you asking ? `DateTime.now.last_month` is used for fetching last month, what string do you have to convert in to date?

Comment: If I used `DateTime.now.last_month` it will return June 03, 2018, I want to return June 25, 2018 instead that why I want to fix the day as 25.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I properly understood what you are looking for, you are after getting 25th of the previous month. Use [`Time#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-c-new):

```
ma = (DateTime.now - 1.month)
#⇒ Sun, 03 Jun 2018 11:07:24 +0200
DateTime.new(ma.year, ma.month, 25, 0, 0, 0, "+00:00")
#⇒ Mon, 25 Jun 2018 00:00:00 +0000
```

Now compare whatever you want against it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this for getting 25th date of month

```
 DateTime.current.last_month.beginning_of_month + 24.days
 => Mon, 25 Jun 2018 00:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

[@mudasobwa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/mudasobwa) answer will work.

But I guess it can be done a little bit safer from using `- 1.month` by using `.ago`

Example: `ma = 1.month.ago`

Then you can add this piece that he wrote: `DateTime.new(ma.year, ma.month, 25, 0, 0, 0, "+00:00")`

Also when you can compare the dates, it's better to use UTC so you don't compare two datetimes with different timezones

Example: `if your_datetime.utc > ma.utc`

Comment: Is `+00:00` the time zone? Does changing it to `+08:00` will make it GMT +8 (Singapore, Manila) Time?

Comment: `+00:00` is UTC, If you set the timezone of your server to (Singapore, Manila), You should set `ma` to this timezone to have an accurate comparison. 

You can change the timezone of your datetime object like that `ma.in_time_zone('Asia/Singapore')`.

You can find all the timezone codes here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: LOL “safer.” FYI: `1.month.ago` calls `- 1.month` [under the hood](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L366).

Comment: I didn't say it was incorrect, I mentioned in the first line that your answer is correct and will work (I also upvoted it). Thanks for sharing the code itself. I think my meaning of safety exists in the method `sum` in the `duration.rb`. `1.month` just really represents an integer in the end. Using `ago` gives you these some extra checks. Sorry if my answer felt insulting in any way, it's not. and thanks again for sharing the link.